# iOS using XMPP connects to ejabberd failed

Tags: ios, xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework

I'm using https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework to connect to my own ejabberd server, but it always failed after negotiation.

here is the log I got:
2014-01-17 07:14:40.780 Chat[48246:70b] error: (null)

2014-01-17 07:14:40.789 Chat[48246:70b] xmppStreamWillConnect

2014-01-17 07:14:46.076 Chat[48246:70b] socketDidConnect

2014-01-17 07:14:46.077 Chat[48246:70b] xmppStreamDidStartNegotiation

2014-01-17 07:14:51.799 Chat[48246:70b] xmppStreamDidDisconnect: Error Domain=GCDAsyncSocketErrorDomain Code=7 "Socket closed by remote peer" UserInfo=0x918d2e0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Socket closed by remote peer}

and here is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.stream = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];
    self.stream.myJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:@"test@gmail.com"];
    self.stream.hostName = @"my host ip";
    self.stream.hostPort = 5222;
    [self.stream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    self.reconnect = [[XMPPReconnect alloc] init];
    [self.reconnect activate:self.stream];

    self.muc = [[XMPPMUC alloc] init];
    [self.muc activate:self.stream];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.stream connectWithTimeout:XMPPStreamTimeoutNone error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
    }
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
}


- (void)xmppStreamWillConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"xmppStreamWillConnect");
}

- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender socketDidConnect:(GCDAsyncSocket *)socket
{
    NSLog(@"socketDidConnect");
}

- (void)xmppStreamDidStartNegotiation:(XMPPStream *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"xmppStreamDidStartNegotiation");
}

- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender willSecureWithSettings:(NSMutableDictionary *)settings
{
    NSLog(@"willSecureWithSettings: %@", settings);
}

- (void)xmppStreamDidSecure:(XMPPStream *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"xmppStreamDidSecure");
}

- (void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"xmppStreamDidConnect");
    NSError *error = nil;
    [self.stream authenticateAnonymously:&error];
    NSLog(@"authenticate: %@", error);
}

- (void)xmppStreamDidRegister:(XMPPStream *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"xmppStreamDidRegister");
}

- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didNotRegister:(NSXMLElement *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didNotRegister: %@", error);

}

- (void)xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:(XMPPStream *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"xmppStreamDidAuthenticate");
}

- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didNotAuthenticate:(NSXMLElement *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didNotAuthenticate: %@", error);
}

- (void)xmppStreamWasToldToDisconnect:(XMPPStream *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"xmppStreamWasToldToDisconnect");
}

- (void)xmppStreamConnectDidTimeout:(XMPPStream *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"xmppStreamConnectDidTimeout");
}


- (void)xmppStreamDidDisconnect:(XMPPStream *)sender withError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"xmppStreamDidDisconnect: %@", error);
}
```

Comment: hey @disorderdev you solved this issue ....then put some code of it ...i have same problem ...

Answer (score 1):

Check if the solution reported here https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/issues/131 solves your issue.

> Generally when the server is closing the connection, you get this
>   error/ Two reasons when the server closes the connection:
>
> 1. You are not sending regular pings if the client idle.
> 2. You are logging in from some different client with the same credentials, and in the server settings have the setting:
>      *Always kick* - If there is a resource conflict, immediately kick the other resource. in Server>server settings>resource policy.

Comment: i have same problem occur ....how to regular ping to server from client can you give idea or suggestion ?