# automatically xmppStreamDidDisconnect invoke in xmpp

Tags: ios, sockets, timeout, xmpp, xmppframework

i have struggling problem of **timeout in xmpp.**

whenever i completed  register my client on server after that exactly **1 min(60 sec)** automatically call the delegate method of xmmppstream

```
 - (void)xmppStreamDidDisconnect:(XMPPStream *)sender withError:(NSError *)error
```

it given me the error message like:

**Error Domain=GCDAsyncSocketErrorDomain Code=7 "Socket closed by remote peer" UserInfo=0xc552bf0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Socket closed by remote peer}**

Any idea on how to resolve this issue will be very helpful. Let me know if you need any additional info.

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

Your server might be configured to ping clients every 60 secs and close sessions which are not respond to XMPP pings. You can activate `XMPPPing` module and set `pingModule.respondsToQueries = YES;` to handle such pings automatically.

Comment: any way XMPPAutoPing or XMPPPing not invoked in my application...i tried as per your suggestion...what to do for resolve ?

Comment: hey please give idea i am total new in this framework @vitalyster can you tell me how to continues ping on server ....like in this say http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21175012/ios-using-xmpp-connects-to-ejabberd-failed

Comment: Read my first answer carefully, you should activate XMPPPing module and enable responds to queries, what is the problem?

Comment: i tried whenever setupstream execute that time auto set XMPPAUTOPING but not success in that ...if you give more info then really appreciated for resolve issue.

Comment: Why you are trying not I'm saying you? Do you have problems with activating extensions? Check iPhoneXMPP example project.